# THREE.js translation/position weirdness

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to generate random planes that would be in random position in the screen and of random size. The problem I have is that I really don't understand the set.position values. What are they representing? I tried to search every where for an answer but couldn't find.
Here's my code for the planes:

```
var planes = [];

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(sizeWidth*((randomSO(1,20)*0.00001)), sizeHeight*((randomSO(1,10)*0.0001)));
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00});
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    plane.drawMode = THREE.TrianglesDrawMode;

    plane.position.set(-10+i, 0, 0);
    scene.add(plane);
    planes[i] = plane;
}
```

The X-co-ordinate in above example isn't how I'd want it but is like that for testing. I would like to work according to screensize, that each plane would locate in random % of the width and height. The width of my screen is 1280 and now when I set the the x co-ordinate to let's say -20 it's already out of the screen. Should I set the Z co-ordinate of the camera differently? I really don't understand the position co-ordinates in this :-(

Comment: As you said about screen size, maybe it's better to use `THREE.OrthographicCamera()`

Comment: Thanks, it worked with the orthographic camera, camera's x & y being 0. Now the left side is -window.innerWidth/2 and right window.innerWidth/2.